# On polynomials associated to integers power sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras, computational-number-theory

For $0\leq k\leq n$ integers let $P_k(n):= n^k,\ S_k(n):= P_k(1)+\ldots P_k(n)= 1^k+\ldots n^k$.

Then $P_k(0)=0$, $S_0(n)=n$.

For calculate $S_1(n)$ i consider:
$$P_2(n)-P_2(n-1)=2n+1$$

then
$\begin{cases} 
P_2(n)-P_2(n-1) = 2n-1 \\ 
P_2(n-1)-P_2(n-2) = 2(n-1)-1\\ 
\ldots \\ 
\ldots\\ 
P_2(1)-P_2(0) = 2\cdot (1)-1\\
\end{cases} $

the left sum is $P_2(n)=n^2$ the right sum is $2\cdot S_1(n)-S_0(n)=2\cdot S_1(n)-n$ then (as well knowed):

$$S_1(n)=\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}$$

Is easy to iterate the process: For calculate $S_2(n)$ i consider:
$$P_3(n)-P_3(n-1)=3n^2-3n+1$$
then:
$\begin{cases} P_3(n)-P_3(n-1) =& 3n^2-3n+1 \\ P_2(n-1)-P_2(n-2) =& 3(n-1)^2-3(n-1)+1
\\ \ldots\\ \ldots\\ P_3(1)-P_3(0) =& 3(1)^2-3(1)+1
%
\end{cases} $

the left sum is $P_3(n)=n^3$ the right sum is $3S_2(n)-3S_1(n)+n$ then from the expression of $S_1(n)$ above we get:

$$S_2(n)=(2n^3+3n^2+n)/6=n(2n^2+3n+1)/6=n(2n+1)(n+1)/6$$
generally, suppose we have already deduced $S_1(n),\ S_2(n),\ldots, S_{k-1}(n)$, for deduce  $S_{k}(n)$ calculate
$$P_{k+1}(n)-P_{k+1}(n-1)= n^{k+1}-(n-1)^{k+1}=n^{k+1}-[\Sigma_{i=0}^{k+1}{k+1\choose i}n^{k+1-i}(-1)^i]=$$
$$=\Sigma_{i=1}^{k+1}{k+1\choose i}n^{k+1-i}(-1)^{i+1}
=\Sigma_{j=0}^{k}{k+1\choose j+1}n^{k-j}(-1)^{j}$$

form the sum $[P_{k+1}(n)-P_{k+1}(n-1)]+[P_{k+1}(n-1)-P_{k+1}(n-2)]+\ldots [P_{k+1}(1)-P_{k+1}(0)]$ we get

$$P_{k+1}(n)=n^{k+1}= \Sigma_{j=0}^{k}{k+1\choose j+1}S_{k-j}(n)\cdot (-1)^{j}={k+1\choose 1}S_{k}(n)+\Sigma_{j=1}^{k}{k+1\choose j+1}S_{k-j}(n)\cdot (-1)^{j} $$

then

$$S_k(n)=\frac{n^{k+1}+\Sigma_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j+1}\cdot {k+1\choose j+1}S_{k-j}(n)}{k+1}=$$
$$\frac{n^{k+1}+{k+1\choose 2}S_{k-1}(n)-{k+1\choose 3}S_{k-2}(n)+{k+1\choose 4}S_{k-3}(n)-\ldots +(-1)^{k}(k+1)\cdot S_1(n)+(-1)^{k+1}\cdot n}{k+1}$$

for example:

$$S_1(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\ S_2(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
,\ S_3(n)=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}=[S_1(n)]^2$$
$$S_4(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}=S_2(n)\cdot \frac{3n^2+3n-1}{5}$$
$$S_5(n)=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)}{12}=S_3(n)\cdot \frac{2n^2+2n-1}{3}$$\

***I ask if (for each k)***:  $$S_k(n)\ divides\ S_{k+2}(n)\ in\ Q[n]$$

Answer (score 5):

No: $S_4(n)=\frac{1}{30}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$ does not divide $S_6(n)=\frac{1}{42}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^4+6n^3-3n+1)$.  Incidentally, these polynomials have been studied extensively and are closely related to Bernoulli numbers.  You can find information about these in the article on Faulhaber's formula on Wikipedia, for example.